# how to extend the length of leaf node in dendrogram and add node labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggdendro

My task is to create a dendrogram, but the leaf nodes shows blunt edges. How would I extend the length of the leaf node, and add node labels?

Please see the current and expected images below.

Data:

```
df1 <- data.frame( z1 = c(rep('P1', 5), rep('P2', 5), rep('P3', 3), rep('P4', 4)),
                   z2 = c(letters[1:5], letters[6:10], letters[11:13], letters[14:17]),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Code:

```
library('data.table')
library('ggplot2')
library('ggdendro')
library('grid')

setDT(df1)
ddata <- dcast( data = df1[, .(z1, z2)],
                formula = z2 ~ z1, 
                fill = 0, 
                fun.aggregate = length, 
                value.var = 'z2')
setDF( ddata)
row.names(ddata) <- ddata$z2
ddata$z2 <- NULL
ddata <- dendro_data( as.dendrogram( hclust( dist( ddata), method = "average")))
p <- ggplot(segment(ddata)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) + 
  theme_dendro()
print(p)
```

Current plot:

[image]

Expected Plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, the simplest is probably to apply a function recursively over the nodes of the dendrogram using `dendrapply`.

If you insert a new line to assign the dendrogram object:

```
dendro <-  as.dendrogram(hclust(dist(ddata), method = "average"))
```

and then create a simple function that reduces the height of leaf nodes by a given amount (d):

```
dropleaf <- function(x, d = 1){
  if(is.leaf(x)) attr(x, "height") <- attr(x, "height") - d
  return(x)
}
```

The function can be applied over all nodes as follows:

```
dendro <- dendrapply(dendro, dropleaf, d = 0.2)
```

If you intend to plot the axis you can re-scale the plot so that the lowest point is reset to zero using:

```
dendro <- phylogram::reposition(dendro, shift = "reset")
```

You can then proceed with the rest of your code..

```
ddata <- dendro_data(dendro)
p <- ggplot(segment(ddata)) + 
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) + 
  theme_dendro()
print(p)
```

producing the following output:

[image: dendrogram]

Comment: `library('dendextend'); as.dendrogram( hclust( dist( ddata), method = "average")) %>% set("hang_leaves", 0.5)` also works. The `fix_height_attr_per_leaf` function inside `dendextend::hang.dendrogram` is similar to the answer above, but not identical.